# Is there a more elegant way to collapse exactly two rows in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a bunch of survey data with issues ranked "Very High" / "High" / "Medium" / "Low" / "Very Low" and I want to summarize it with "High" and "Very High" condensed into a single value.

I want to count the number of times each value was selected, and then calculate the percent that represents. If I wanted to translate this into a starwars census, it would be equivalent to counting all characters (for brevity we'll limit it to feminine characters) by homeworld, but collapsing two worlds into a single value. (This is where I confess that I have no idea which homeworlds actually make sense collapsed together so I picked the first two alphabetically.)

The only way I could come up with to accomplish this was to use calculate the counts and percents, use`bind_rows()` to tack on the new summary row, and then filter out the rows I used to make that summary:

```
  top_two <- c("Alderaan", "Chandrila")
  
  
  my_tmp <- starwars  %>%
    drop_na(homeworld) %>%
    count(homeworld, gender) %>%
    filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
    mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100) %>% 
    select(-gender)
  
  my_tmp <- bind_rows(my_tmp, 
                      my_tmp %>%
                        filter(homeworld  %in% top_two) %>%
                        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~ if (is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Alderaan or Chandrila")))
  
  my_tmp <- my_tmp %>% 
    mutate(percent = sprintf("%.0f%%", percent)) %>%
    filter(!homeworld  %in% top_two) %>%
    arrange(homeworld)
  
  
  my_tmp
```

It works, but it feels very, very clunky. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
starwars %>%
  drop_na(homeworld) %>%
  filter(gender == "feminine") %>%
  mutate(homeworld = ifelse(homeworld %in% top_two,
                            paste(top_two, collapse = " or "),
                            homeworld)) %>%
  count(homeworld) %>%
  mutate(percent = scales::percent(n/sum(n), accuracy = 1))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  homeworld                 n percent
  <chr>                 <int> <chr>  
1 Alderaan or Chandrila     2 13%    
2 Coruscant                 2 13%    
3 Kamino                    1 7%     
4 Mirial                    2 13%    
5 Naboo                     3 20%    
6 Ryloth                    1 7%     
7 Shili                     1 7%     
8 Tatooine                  2 13%    
9 Zolan                     1 7%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think base-R solution

```
starwars$homeworld[starwars$homeworld %in% c('Alderaan', 'Chandrila')] <- 'Alderaandrila'
```

should easily do the trick for you.
If you want to go the `dplyr` way, @Z.Lin's answer above has that :)